# How should I approach a zoom game where it feels like opponents always seem to flop better hands (big raises)

Tags: strategy

I have been trying to grind up the 0,01/0,02 NL zoom tables for a while and when I am losing money, it always seems like opponents bet every single flop big. This also goes for pre-flop play where I have a hand like AQo and get ran over due to re-raisers. This is my first question asked ever so I am sorry if I am not being clear enough.

Thanks in advance , 
Michiel

Comment: This is a vague question - in general if people are betting every flop, you should adjust by raising more or playing tighter. Since zoom is different opponents each time, especially at the micros, its more likely you're running into a lot of big hands and you're playing too many hands.

Comment: In my experience with _zoom_, when people re-raising preflop, you need to find if they're regulars (eg. stats). If they're regs, you're dead with `AQ` hands. In the same manner, when a regular bets big a flop, you're often looking a set and be dead as well. Zoom is a game of monsters preflop and postflop, that's more true in micro-stakes.

Answer (score 1):

This happens to everybody in poker at times. It is important to keep your cool during periods like this and just keeping making the correct folds. Most players at these stakes are really passive and they usually have exactly what they are representing.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're playing against really loose aggressive players (very typical in zoom, along with very tight players. Not much middle ground) One good way to play against them is to wait for really premium hands and be super aggressive. So if they raise, raise them back. If they come over the top, I like to just call and then bet big/raise on the flop. Or you can keep raising until you're all in, but remember you still only have two cards, and haven't made your hand yet.

EDIT: Also, at the micro levels you're playing at, no one will take it seriously. That's why people are raising so much. It's cheap, but if they flop a monster they stand to make a few bucks. Honestly, playing .01/.02 NL zoom is just a donkfest, try to get your money in good, but expect to get sucked out on a lot too.

Comment: So your suggestion is to raise often, or call, or maybe fold because you really only have two cards after all.

Comment: No... my suggestions is to raise when you have a great starting hand, otherwise fold. Notice I said "wait for really premium hands." Then when you do play a hand, don't assume that because you have AA you're guaranteed to win. Play strong, but realize you still can lose.

Comment: I guess a vague question is asking for a vague answer.